# Enable to import csv properly

Tags: angular

I have created the following app = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6r12ta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

This imports a csv file. But I have 2 problems:

1. I have had to put double quotes around the speech string in order to escape the commas put inside them (I know this is standard practice). However I want to remove them on import.
2. If there is a comma in the speech string, the app doesn't import it at all. I'm assuming it's a problem where I'm splitting the commas.

Stackoverlow doesn't allow me to upload a file for you to test, but here is some text that you could copy into a csv file:

```
id,speechText
84983428,"I can't pick up a person"
51489463,"I don't think you've thought this through properly"
58345,"This line won't import, because it has a comma"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't handle the cases where comma is present in the rows. The following line is the problem -

```
let curruntRecord = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(",");
      if (curruntRecord.length == headerLength) {...}
```

This condition won't match if there is at least one comma in one of the cells.

You should use a proper csv parser. I've modified your code using [ngx-csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-csv-parser).

**Install**

```
npm install --save ngx-csv-parser
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgxCsvParserModule } from "ngx-csv-parser";

imports: [..., NgxCsvParserModule],
```

**app.component.ts**

-- your modified uploadListener method --

```
uploadListener($event: any): void {
    let text = [];
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {
      this.ngxCsvParser.parse(files[0], { header: false, delimiter: ',' })
      .pipe().subscribe((result: Array<any>) => {
 
        console.log('Result', result);
        this.records = result;
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }
```